# unknown variable in nested block java

Tags: java

I used "e" varible  instead of goto!
in my code "e" variable is unknown

```
int e=1;

while(e==1)
{
    if (now.getMinute() == end_minute && now.getSecond() >= second ) break;
    new java.util.Timer().schedule(new java.util.TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("hello!");
            if (now.getMinute() == end_minute && now.getSecond() >= second ) e=0;
        }
    }, 60000);  
}
```

thanks.

Comment: Please.format.your.code. Thanks.

Comment: Besides that, it looks like you mean `e=0` inside the `TimerTask` is unknown. That's because you create an anonymous inner class which can see method local variables like `e` only if they are declared as `final` (you can't change them then ofc).

Comment: to make use of the local variable `e` in an anonymous class you´d have to define `e` as final, whereas `e=0` would´t work anymore. You might want to wrap it in a class, to be able to modify the value .

Comment: Another thought on your design: you're spawning new tasks and timers until you reach the minute and second you defined. That might cause a whole lot of timers and tasks to be created.

Comment: i want use "e" instead of goto :|

Comment: Also, the e variable should be a boolean value, rather than an int. It's only meaningful to have a true or false value there.

Comment: You should describe what you are trying to do, since your code seems weird on many aspects.

Comment: No write access to effectively final variables (except initialisation)!!!

Comment: if i use label for goto !        
        ll:
    while(true)
            {
                new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
                new java.util.TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("hello!");
                    if (now.getMinute() == end_minute && now.getSecond() == second ) 
                    {
                        break ll ;
                    }

            }
        }, 
        60000 
);
     

    
    } error: "invalid label"!

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this one?

```
package general;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class TestTimer {
public static int e = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    int end_minute = 45;
    int second = 30;

    while(e==1)
    {

        if (now.getMinute() == end_minute && now.getSecond() >= second ) break;
        new java.util.Timer().schedule(new java.util.TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("hello!");
                if (now.getMinute() == end_minute && now.getSecond() >= second ) 
                    e=0;
            }
        }, 60000);  
    }


}
```

}